# Ratio of an inscribed circle's tangent to original square

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

In the diagram, the circle is inscribed within square $PQRS,$ $\overline{UT}$ is tangent to the circle, and $RU$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ of $RS.$ What is $\frac{RT}{RQ}$?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the circle touches $RS$, $TU$ and $RQ$ at $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.

If $RQ=4$, $RU=1$. Let $RT=x$.

Then $TU=TY+YU=TZ+XU=2-x+1$.

So $1^2+x^2=(3-x)^2$ and thus $1+x^2=9-6x+x^2$.

$\displaystyle x=\frac{4}{3}$.

$\displaystyle \frac{RT}{RQ}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Circle has equation $x^2+y^2=4$

$U(1;\;-2)$

The equation of a general line passing through $U$ is

$mx-y-m-2=0$

This line is tangent to the circle if its distance from the center is equal to the radius, that is
$$\frac{|-m-2|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=2\to m^2+4m+4=4m^2+4\to m_1=0;\;m_2=\frac{4}{3}$$

One tangent is the line containing $RS$ the other is the line $UT$

$y=\dfrac{4}{3}x-\dfrac{10}{3}$

which for $x=2$ gives $y=-\dfrac{2}{3}$ and $RT=2-\dfrac{2}{3}=\dfrac{4}{3}$

This means $\dfrac{RT}{RQ}=\dfrac{\frac{4}{3}}{4}=\dfrac{1}{3}$

Hope this can be useful

[image]